# How can my Q-learning agent trained to solve a specific maze generalize to other mazes?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, function-approximation, generalization, state-representations

I implemented Q-learning to solve a specific maze. However, it doesn't solve other mazes. How could my Q-learning agent be able to generalize to other mazes?

Comment: Technically your q-learning algorithm can solve *any* maze through trial and error, but has to start learning from scratch if given a new maze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you're using the standard, basic, simple variant of $Q$-learning that can be described as **tabular** $Q$-learning, where all of your state-action pairs for which you're learning $Q(s, a)$ values are represented in a tabular fashion. For example, if you have 4 actions, your $Q(s, a)$ values are likely represented by 4 matrices (corresponding to the 4 actions), where every matrix has the same dimensionality as your maze *(I'm assuming that your maze is a grid of discrete cells here)*.

With such an approach, you are learning $Q$ values separately for every single individual state (+ action). Such learned values will always only be valid for **one particular maze** (the one you have been training in), as you seem to have already noticed. This is a direct consequence of the fact that you're learning individual values for specific state-action pairs. The things you are learning ($Q$ values) can therefore not directly be transferred to a different maze; **those particular states from the first maze do not even exist in the second maze!**

Better results may be achievable with different state representations. For example, instead of representing states by their coordinates in a grid (as you would likely do with a tabular approach), you'd want to describe states in a more general way. For example, a state could be described by features such as:

- Is there a wall right in front of me?
- Is there a wall immediately to my right?
- Is there a wall immediately to my left?

An alternative that also may actually be able to better generalize to some extent could be pixel-based inputs if you have images (a top-down image or even a first-person-view).

When states are represented by such features, you can no longer use the tabular RL algorithms that you are likely familiar with though. You'd have to use **function approximation** instead. With good state-representations, those techniques may have a chance of generalizing. You'd probably want to make sure to actually also use a variety of different mazes during the training process though, otherwise they'd likely still overfit to only a single maze used in training.